# PHP loop ignore output if before today

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I created a loop that displays the courses (custom post type) that are created within the Wordpress theme. However, this loop also displays the courses that were held before today, which is why I added a check on `$date_start` and replaces the date with `Ingen kommende kurser` if the date is earlier than today.

However, what I want is that it completely ignores the instances that have a `date_start` from before today. What happens now is the following:

If a date is from before today, it gets replaced with `Ingen kommende kurser` (no future courses). If there is one of the three displayed courses, it outputs like this:

- Ingen kommende kurser
- Ingen kommende kurser
- Thu. 06 March 2014

What I need is that the dates from before today get completely ignored, because it might be there is a course after March 6, which does not get displayed now.

This is the loop:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
    $category_course = get_the_category(2);
    $cat_slug_course = $category_course[0]->slug;
    $date_start = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'date_start', true);
    $date_start = date("D, M d, Y", $date_start);
    if( strtotime($date_start) > strtotime('now') ) { ?>
        <li>                            
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="date_fp"><?php echo $date_start; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <li>                            
            Ingen kommende kurser
        </li>
    <?php }
}   ?>
```

Which results in:

[image]

So, in short:

Ignore data from the loop if `date_start` is before today. When there is no data to display at all (when all `date_start`s are before today), it should display `Ingen kommende kurser`.

Comment: So if I got it right, it should either display all the dates or if no dates at all, display `Ingen kommende kurser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your while, set a flag:

```
$empty = true;
```

Inside the loop, after the `if` statement, set the flag to false:

```
    if( strtotime($date_start) > strtotime('today') ) { ?>
        <li>                            
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="date_fp"><?php echo $date_start; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php $empty = false; }
```

Remove the entire `else` part, then at the end, check for your flag

```
}
if($empty) { ?>
    <li>                            
        Ingen kommende kurser
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

What this does is first determine the list is empty. Then in the loop, if an item is valid and appears in the list, the empty flag is set to false to mark that the list is no longer empty. After checking all entries, if the list is still empty, it includes your default empty list entry.

**Edit**
I just saw your comment on the other answer. You can easily adapt the flag to work as a counter. Just declare it as `$items = 0;`, then inside the `if`, use `$items++;` instead of `$empty = false;` and at the end, check for `if($items==0)`. Also, your loop condition should be expanded to `while( $loop->have_posts() AND $items < 3 )`.

Comment: Lovin' it! :D I'm more of a frontend-developer, so this is a bit out of my comfort zone, haha!

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the date that is before or after today (whatever you want), like you are already doing and use the [continue keyword](https://www.php.net/continue) from php to skip that iteration.

Comment: That works partially, but I guess Wordpress is the culprit here: It runs through the loop three times, after that it just stops. `Continue` works, but the output is only one date (as only one of the three instances is after today). What I need is all dates after today, with a max of three, so I guess I have to cram that into the PHP loop, not in the WP_Query. Edit: I removed the 'posts_per_page' requirement from `$args`, which solves it partially. Just have to figure out the max 3 now.

Comment: Just use a counter and count to 3, when it has reached 3 you can break the loop with [break](http://nl3.php.net/break).

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
    $category_course = get_the_category(2);
    $cat_slug_course = $category_course[0]->slug;
    $date_start = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'date_start', true);
    if( strtotime($date_start) > strtotime('today') ) { ?>
        <li>                            
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="date_fp"><?php echo $date_start; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <li>                            
            Ingen kommende kurser
        </li>
    <?php }
    }   ?>
```

Comment: This is just the same minus the date format conversion, how does this help?

Comment: That just replaces all instances with "Ingen kommende kurser". Could you explain what it should do?

Comment: @Rvervuurt strtotime('now') return timestamp for the current time, while strtotime('today') return timestamp for "0:00" today.

Comment: I don't understand Danish and didn't know the meaning of "Ingen kommende kurser". And thank you for downvote!

Comment: You don't have to understand Danish, because I translated it for you in the 3rd paragraph. I explained very well what the problem was, and your solution has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote. But the problem was (and I believe that was rather clear in the question even if you don't know what the string means) that he wanted the items with a wrong date to not be displayed at all. The replacement string was supposed to be displayed only if no items would appear at all. Your answer removes the date format conversion and compares to today instead of now, which does absolutely nothing towards the issue.